# Consulta a Web Service con MySQL y PHP con INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, webservice, phpmyadmin

Tengo un problema con una consulta, en mi base de datos tengo dos tablas una tabla que se llama viajes y la otra que se llama like, lo que quiero hacer es crear un WebService y que me devuelva los datos en formato JSON, el problema es que si ejecuto la siguiente consulta en phpmyadmin me devuelve toda la información tanto de mi tabla viaje como de mi tabla like, la consulta es esta:

> SELECT * FROM `post_viajes` INNER JOIN registro_usuarios ON
>   registro_usuarios.idUsuario LIKE like_post GROUP BY
>   registro_usuarios.idUsuario

y lo que me devuelve es esto en formato JSON:

```
{
    "idPost": "1",
    "nombre_usuario": "Enrique",
    "descripcion_post": "Primer post de prueba con like",
    "imagen_post": "https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/Travel/2019/August/iStock-1047662500.jpg",
    "video_post": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rbnI6nCmws",
    "fecha_post": "23/04/2020",
    "like_post": []
}
```

EL problema es que en donde dice "like_post":[] no me devuelve los datos de la tabla like, no se como debo de estructurar mi archivo PHP para que me lo devuelva de la siguiente forma:

```
{
        "idPost": "1",
        "nombre_usuario": "Enrique",
        "descripcion_post": "Primer post de prueba con like",
        "imagen_post": "https://www.telegraph.co.uk/content/dam/Travel/2019/August/iStock-1047662500.jpg",
        "video_post": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rbnI6nCmws",
        "fecha_post": "23/04/2020",
        "like_post": [{"idUsuario": "1",
                       "nombre_usuario": "Enrique"}]
```

}

Este es mi archivo PHP que funciona como Web Service:

```
<?PHP
$servername="localhost";
$database="viajes_mgrex";
$username="root";
$password="";

$json = array();
$jsonLike = array();

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password,$database);
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8");
    //$consulta = "SELECT * FROM post_viajes ORDER BY idPost DESC";
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM post_viajes INNER JOIN registro_usuarios ON registro_usuarios.idUsuario LIKE like_post ORDER BY idPost DESC";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

    while($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){

        $registroFinal["idPost"] = $registro["idPost"];
        $registroFinal["nombre_usuario"] = $registro["nombre_usuario"];
        $registroFinal["descripcion_post"] = $registro["descripcion_post"];
        $registroFinal["imagen_post"] = $registro["imagen_post"];
        $registroFinal["video_post"] = $registro["video_post"];
        $registroFinal["fecha_post"] = $registro["fecha_post"];
        $registroFinal["like_post"] = array();  
        $json = $registroFinal;
    }


    mysqli_close($conexion);
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Esta es la estructura de mi tabla post_viajes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esta es la estructura de tabla usuarios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El campo like_post funciona como llave foranea que me conecta entra mis tablas, el campo like_post en la tabla post_viajes es mi llave primaria de mi tabla usuarios.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar la estructura o diagrama de tus dos tablas? Además de saber qué contiene el campo "like" y de dónde estás sacando o quieres sacar esa información ya que veo que su valor es una lista de usuarios.

Comment: @FernandoTorres ya agregue la estructura de tablas, el campo like saca información de la tabla usuarios

Answer (score 0):

Poner

```
SELECT  FROM post_viajes 
INNER JOIN registro_usuarios ON registro_usuarios.idUsuario =like_post 
GROUP BY registro_usuarios.idUsuario
```

En vez de

```
SELECT * FROM post_viajes 
INNER JOIN registro_usuarios ON registro_usuarios.idUsuario LIKE like_post 
GROUP BY registro_usuarios.idUsuario
```

Comment: Si lo hago de esa forma que tun indicas si funciona, pero ahora tengo otra duda, si un post tiene mas de un like, como deberia de recuperar mas de un valor en el campo like_post, deberia de crear una nueva tabla que haga referencia a las tablas mediante los id y la llave foranea o como podria hacer esto